# How to have access to int passed by a url to a php page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the below URL generated

```
http://localhost/_/globe/ProductsList.php?idd=1015
```

here is the code generating the URL

```
window.location.href="ProductsList.php?idd=" + val;
```

is there any possible way to store 1015 into a PHP session in ProductsList.php ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: This is always an option: http://bit.ly/SIysyb

Comment: @dev - `window.location.href` means the user is being redirected to that URL.

Comment: @Lix Which means, when he gets to the new URL, he can parse the URL, split the params with '=' and store the *idd* in a session var.

Comment: @dev - There would be no need to re-parse the URL. The magic `$_GET` variable will already be set. If the OP was talking about parsing a string, then `parse_url()` would be the way to go.

Comment: Agreed. I was simply giving him the "do a little research" answer.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is inspect the `$_GET` variable.

You'll see that your parameter is located in the `idd` key:

```
session_start(); // initialize the session or connect to an existing one.
$_SESSION[ "idd" ] = $_GET[ "idd" ];
```

You might want to include some sort of logic to ensure that that parameter was in fact passed to the script and if not, set a default value or display an appropriate error.

Comment: forgot `session_start()`

Comment: @Lix Its slightly wrong!

Comment: @muh - are you talking about the capital "S"? :P

Answer (score 2):

$_GET is an array of each variable passed in the url.
Each passed variable is assigned as a unique key to the $_GET array so,  in ProductsList.php you would:

```
session_start()   //Only once in your page to make sure php knows it will have to deal with session information
$_SESSION['idd'] = $_GET['idd']

echo $_SESSION['idd'];
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

On ProductsList.php,

You can use GET method to retrieve url or query string value and store it in an variable as:

```
  $q=$_GET['idd'];
```

Now if you want to store this value in session then try this on ProductsList.php

```
<?php session_start();
  $q=$_GET['idd'];
$_SESSION['session_variable']=$q; //this will store $q value

?>
```